# Can we remove badge for editing posts? re: excessive editing

Tags: feature-request

I hate to pick on rk. because he is a good contributor, and I have seen a few other people engage in this behavior too.

But when I log onto this site, and see something like this, it bothers me because it pushes down other people's questions.  I don't mind people doing benign badge-whoring, but I think this particular one is damaging to other people's threads.

Can we consider removing the badge for editing other people's posts?  I'm sure there are other ways too. (e.g. limit edits/day.  cap the top badge at bronze. etc)

**EDIT:** I'm not just referring to minor content edit.  I'm also referring to Tag edits.  It makes no sense that Tag edit results in thread getting bumped to the top.

[image]

Comment: I disagree that some edits shouldn't bump up the front page - edits move to the front so that other people can view and triage changes to posts. Otherwise I could tag loads of old questions with `jonamazingapp.co.uk` or `this-guy-is-an-idiot` tag and nobody would ever notice that spam / vandalism unless they accidentally stumble upon it. However, the point of the question - about flooding the front page with old posts - is a valid concern and other people do voice this issue both here and on other StackExchange sites.

Comment: @jonw tag vandalism is a valid concern, but I don't think that's a good reason for bumping the thread to the top.  If that truly is a big problem, the there are other ways to deal with it, like higher threshold for creating new tags, and/or new-tag moderation queue.

Comment: @JungLee This particular spree was for removing unnecessary tags. If you open up chat and scroll to this time period, you can see the conversation :) http://imgur.com/uPxLoei

Comment: @rk. I've seen this mass-bumps one too many times.  Had it been an isolated incident, I wouldn't have rocked the boat.  But I'm glad you were mindful of the adverse consequences of mass-retag.  Again, I don't have problems with people re-tagging for benefits of others and scoring some points in the process, but the mass-bump hurts other people's threads, and slowly damages the forum when done in excess by people.  Retagging shouldn't bump threads because it doesn't involve content change. Most folks probably don't even know why certain threads get resurrected and bumped to the top.

Comment: @JungLee I am not denying the bumping at all. Also, imagine this scenario where bumping is not allowed. People post 8-12 questions in a day, 3-4 are closed in a short period of time. A couple questions are quite interesting to a large audience while the remaining questions are not that appealing to everyone. While, the slightly older interesting questions are geting buried under the stack since only questions which are broadly applicable will have more than a couple answers.

Comment: continued ... When I or anyone else 'bumps' the question, it is brought back into the general view. Getting another opportunity to be viewed by the public (maybe even a new set of eyes). I feel this is not detrimental to the purpose of the site.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you assume rk's (or other people's) motivation for editing questions is getting a badge? Maybe they just had some spare time and wanted to contribute back to the site by going through the review queue and doing what they could, which ended up manifesting itself in the form of edited questions.

So I don't think removing the badge would fix the problem. Instead, what you might mean is that you'd prefer for recently edited questions to not take over the homepage. In which case I have to argue that editing a question is an indicator of activity on that question, which means that it should be surfaced on the site so people can re-evaluate it.

Comment: I agree with your latter point: editing your OWN post should get your thread bumped to the top.  I have not seen people abuse that to bump their unanswered threads, which is why I didn't suggest that in the first place.  People love to help out others, but it would be naive to assume that badges don't motivate people, which is why SE has them in the first place.  Ultimately, I don't care what the intent was.  I don't thinking minor edits of other people's post or Tag Edits should result in thread getting bumped.  It hurts other threads when done in excess.